# Keep text in textarea highlighted after focus changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a text editor that has a feature like Microsoft Word. I want the user to be able to highlight some text, and then adjust the font size of the highlighted text by clicking on a text `<input>` and typing in a font size. However, whenever the user clicks on the text input, the text from the text area becomes unhighlighted. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Why not use a robust solution like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) ? You can choose which options are available to the user, and there is a great community from which you can get help.

Comment: I'm working for a company, and changing their text editor which is already a big project. Thanks though.

Comment: You cannot style part of the text in a `<textarea>` control.  It's all or nothing.